# How do I use selenium with docker-compose

Tags: selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, selenium-docker

I just want to open the driver with selenium-docker, but for some reason I can't connect to the host

My repository:

https://github.com/ribeirosaimon/selenium_teste

<< I need to wait Browser, Thx! >>

Answer (score 1):

Your chrome node is attached to different network that other services. Remove any mentioning of networks from your docker-compose.yaml.

Docker-compose creates temporary bridge network by default for the services which are started from one file.

Comment: got the answer. My grid is slower than my app so I should put a 'sleep'